# Is the expression “to run someone out” an actual saying?

Tags: slang

I’ve hear it before, but can’t seem to find an actually source that says it is a common phrase used. As far as I know, it means to kick someone out. But let me know if you’ve used it before or if it is correct to use such expression.

Comment: What do you mean "slang" there, buckeroo?

Comment: It is a common expression. I have heard it all my life. To run someone out is more forceful and faster than to kick someone out. A man may be kicked out of a bar by the bar's owner, but he is run out of a town by several people acting together.

Comment: There's a strong distinction in my part of the US between *run someone out **of** someplace* and *run someone out **to** someplace*. The former has the meaning you describe, and is relatively rare (because, fortunately, the action is nowadays rare). The latter means *to take someone (usually in a car) to the location* and is pretty common. As in "I promised to run my neighbor out to the airport tomorrow* or *I'll be in right after I run my kid out to pick up some school supplies we forgot*. The "out" can often be omitted; I think it shows up especially when the destination is outside of town.

Answer (score 1):

**to run someone out** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/157528?rskey=9I571v&result=1#eid91448837)

> P5. orig. U.S. to ride (also **run) a person (out)** on a rail: to
>   carry or parade a person astride a rail as a punishment (now hist.);
>   (fig.) to punish or drive away with ridicule.

Yes, it is correct AmE, as in:

1935   *J. T. Farrell Judgment Day*

> They ought to be jailed, run out of town on a rail, tarred and
>   feathered.

and

1975   J. Gores Hammett

> They just about ran him out of St. Mary's County, Maryland, on a rail.

and

1991   *Outrage*

> They're probably not fresh faces at all—perhaps they've just been
>   ridden out of Adelaide on a rail.

Comment: A batsman or batswoman can be 'run out' in cricket.